# Why can’t I call jQuery methods stored within an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, methods

The buttons are supposed to execute `show`, `hide`, `toggle`, etc. functions on the image, but they do not work as intended. I have been told that I am destroying the reference to `this` inside the `show`, `hide`, etc. functions. How can I fix that?

```js
/// <reference path="jquery-3.3.1.js" />

var functionArray = [$('img').show, $('img').hide, $('img').toggle, $('img').fadeIn, $('img').fadeOut, $('img').fadeToggle];
var buttonArray = [$('.show'), $('.hide'), $('.toggle'), $('.fadein'), $('.fadeout'), $('.fadetog')]
var counter = 0

while (counter < buttonArray.length) {
  executer(counter)
  counter++
}

function executer(counter) {
  buttonArray[counter].click(function() {
    functionArray[counter]();
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://placehold.it/300x50" />
<br />
<button class="show">Show</button>
<button class="hide">Hide</button>
<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
<button class="fadein">Fade in</button>
<button class="fadeout">Fade out</button>
<button class="fadetog">Fade toggle</button>

<!-- Script sources in the original code:
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Script1.js"></script>
-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re right, the context gets lost when you store a method separately from its object.

Since the context object is the same for all methods, the easiest way here to solve this, is to not store the context object at all, but just the method names.

`functionArray` would then contain just the method names as strings; then they can be accessed and called by `$("img")[functionArray[counter]]();`.

Expand this snippet to see the working code in action:

```js
var functionArray = [
    "show",
    "hide",
    "toggle",
    "fadeIn",
    "fadeOut",
    "fadeToggle"
  ],
  buttonArray = [
    $('.show'),
    $('.hide'),
    $('.toggle'),
    $('.fadein'),
    $('.fadeout'),
    $('.fadetog')
  ],
  counter = 0;

while (counter < buttonArray.length) {
  executer(counter);
  counter++;
}

function executer(counter) {
  buttonArray[counter].click(function() {
    $("img")[functionArray[counter]]();
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://placehold.it/300x50" />
<br />
<button class="show">Show</button>
<button class="hide">Hide</button>
<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
<button class="fadein">Fade in</button>
<button class="fadeout">Fade out</button>
<button class="fadetog">Fade toggle</button>
```